# Send Cognos Burst Reporting to multiple emails

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I have a few reports that need to be sent form hourly certain intervals during the day.

I know how to schedule burst jobs and they send out fine, but i am being tasked with sending that same exact thing to "CC" that persons mananagerl1 and managerl2

Lets say part of the email table looks like

```
Name   |  mgr1   | mgr2 |  email  |  mgr1eml   | mgr2email
```

normally i burst to  email and group by name

how would i burst to all three emails without having to create 3 different reports?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  That said, look into using Event Studio to perform customized emailing with bursts.  You can feed different variables in the TO and CC separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think you can do it this way:
Use a comma delimited string for your email addresses:

```
blah@blahblah.com,foobar@foobar.com,...
```

Set your burst property to email addresses (Report Studio > File menu > Burst Options > Burst Recipient > Type).

Answer (score 1):

To burst multiple groups with different hierarchies without creating multiple reports

For example, 
a sales report with three levels of reporting -- branch managers, supervisors, and sales reps

- The branch managers need to see the supervisors and sales reps that belong to them
- The supervisors need to see the sales reps that belong to them
- The sales reps should only see the orders that belong to them

So if we had 2 branch managers, each with 3 supervisors, and each supervisor has 4 sales reps

We would need to burst the report 20 times with 3 different groupings
This could be done with 3 reports or with 1 report that has 3 views

**Solution**

- Create a prompt page with a value prompt to define the different groupings that will be used
- Start with one list that includes all of the groupings that will be needed
- Add to the query a data item for burst group and recipient
- Define the data items based on the prompt page variable that defines the grouping
- Create different list (from the same query), one for each group (at any hierarchy), grouping by the new data item
  As a suggestion, for each list - use a text item to control the column heading. Or you could make a data item for the headings as well
- Create a string variable based on the prompt variable
- Render each list based on the variable from the prompt
- Create a view from the report for each burst requirement
- Set the prompt value for each view
- Schedule the views

Any changes to the report will be seen in the views so you only have to maintain one report

You might want to try creating a job, then add the views to the job so you only have to schedule the job