# How schedule Cognos to send one report to both the static email list plus query results email list as recipients

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I want to schedule an outgoing Cognos 10 report to be emailed to a changing list of email addresses which change according to a Query results plus 3 static email addresses that do not change.

(Originally I bursted and used a join to join in static recipients, but the requestor does not want to receive bursted reports.  But they only want **one** report to be sent to everyone on that days query result plus static cc list.)

For example today the report may be emailed to:

```
mailto: new_email_addr1, new_email_addr2
    cc: static_addr1, static_addr2, static_addr3
```

Tomorrow perhaps changes to:

```
mailto: new_email_addr8, new_email_addr13, new_email_addr2
    cc: static_addr1, static_addr2, static_addr3
```

Notice, cc email address stay the same.

Only 1 email should go out to each recipient each day and will include all results, thus not a bursted report in the usual way I understand it.  All recipients receive identical report.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Side thought:  Would it just be a matter of changing the joined email query result to link to itself in the Burst options? ie. one query containing static email plus query result addresses joined to itself in Master Relationship detail?  Just throwing this out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use bursting.  Join the bursting query to the report in a way that produces a single report.  (ie, Put them all in the same "group".)  If needed, you can do this by including in both queries a query item that is defined as a constant.  (For example, the data item name may be `BurstJoin` and its expression may be `'a'`.)

If the three static email addresses are not in the source data, you can add them by UNIONing the EmailAddress query with three other queries, each returning a single record for each of the static email addresses.

Since Cognos is so graphical, it's difficult to show here.  In SQL, the final query returning the email addresses for bursting may look like...

```
SELECT 'a' AS BurstJoin
, EmailAddress
FROM TableListingEmailAddresses

UNION SELECT 'a' AS BurstJoin
, 'joe@example.com' AS EmailAddress

UNION SELECT 'a' AS BurstJoin
, 'sally@example.com' AS EmailAddress

UNION SELECT 'a' AS BurstJoin
, 'bob@example.com' AS EmailAddress
```

Or, maybe, the query (or the column) for the cc list would need to be different?  I haven't done bursting with a cc list in a while?

Comment: Thanks.  I created and grouped on added static dataitem 'a' and works fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can see master detail might work if you need multiple queries.

If you can get the result in a single query (because one set is static and never changes) 
A data item for the static emails.  The other data item for the query based results
Using a comma delimited string for your email addresses, you can just combine data items

Relevant post for sending to multiple addresses
[Send Cognos Burst Reporting to multiple emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359953/send-cognos-burst-reporting-to-multiple-emails)

Comment: Thanks.  I "Unioned" the static email list with the original list (using a filter on the static list to ensure only those 4 addresses included).    Then joined on common field added to both queries "a".   Seems to be working good. Thanks for taking the time  !